# JQuery clickin' buttons

Tags: jquery

I'm making a small game for a school project, and basically there are 20 boxes. 10 boxes have a value of -2, 5 boxes have a value of 2, 3 boxes have a value of 0, and 2 boxes have a value of -5 and 5. So my question is, how can I determine which box was clicked with which value?

Code to initialize my boxes:

```
shuffle(numbers); // number.length is 20
for(var i = 0; i < numbers.length; ++i)
{
    $('#buttons').append('<button class="boxes" id="' + numbers[i] + '">' + numbers[i] + '</button>');
}
```

Code that I have tried:

```
$('#buttons').append('<button class="boxes" id="' + numbers[i] + '" onclick="clicked(this);">' + numbers[i] + '</button>'); // made function called clicked with alert in return

$('button#-2).click(function () {
    alert('Clicked on -2 box');
});
```

But it seems like none of this code seems to show me an alert for which box I clicked. Am I missing something?

Comment: If you have values in `numbers` that start with anything other than A-Z or a-z then your HTML will be invalid (the ID attribute can only start with an alpha character).  I doubt this would break your functionality, but it's a bad habit to get into.

Comment: @Abe [Not quite](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#the-id-attribute). In HTML5 it can be any char but a space, although it will probably break jQuery and many old CSS engines. i.e. `<div id="✰"></div>` is perfectly valid.

Comment: @Andrew, thanks for the heads up.  This is proof that I need to get familiar with HTML5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than relying on the ID for the boxes to know what their values are (which is bad because IDs are supposed to be unique), you can use the text inside of the button.  If you're not actually supposed to have that in their text (I assume this is a guessing game?), you can use a data attribute to assign them values:

```
var buttons = $('#buttons');
for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    $('<button class="boxes"></button>')
        .data('number', numbers[i])
        .click(function() { alert('Clicked on ' + $(this).data('number')); })
        .appendTo(buttons);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To know which boxes is clicked you could do that :

```
$('.button').click(function() {
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
    alert($(this).html());
});
```

The first alert will show you the id of the box clicked
The second will show you the value of the box clicked

Answer (score 0):

you have a little syntax problem in your append, this is how it works:

```
for(var i = 0; i < numbers.length; ++i)
{
    $('#buttons').append('<button class="boxes" id="button' 
                        + numbers[i] + '">' + numbers[i] + '</button>');
}
```

and you can use the same function to handle all clicks

```
function click_handler(){
    alert('Clicked on ' + this.id);
}

$('button.boxes').click(click_handler);
```

Try the example in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YEC6Y/)